# ruby on rails use "create" method in controller as GET not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

**friendships_controller.rb**

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  # POST /friendships
  # POST /friendships.json
  def create

    #@friendship = Friendship.new(params[:friendship])
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friendship.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile(current_user.username), notice: 'Friendship was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @friendship, status: :created, location: @friendship }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile(current_user.username), notice: 'Friendship was not created.' }
        format.json { render json: @friendship.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /friendships/1
  # DELETE /friendships/1.json
  def destroy
    @friendship = Friendship.find(params[:id])
    @friendship.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to friendships_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

when i go to `http://localhost:3000/friendships?friend_id=1` i get

```
Unknown action

The action 'index' could not be found for FriendshipsController
```

I followed this tutorial : http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably configured the create as a POST not a GET.

```
  # POST /friendships
  # POST /friendships.json
  def create
```

This is also the case if you used scaffolding to create a skeleton of your controller. You could change this in the routes configuration. But be aware, that creating stuff via GET is no longer seen as completely conform to the REST paradigm.

Comment: i will go through ajax on these friendship requests but since i am getting started i thought i would follow the tutorial listed above but then i got into that problem... also looked up on the tutorial source code and i can't find anything weird on the routes that changes the POST of create into GET...

Comment: There is a bit on routing on this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html - the standard entry would probably be something like: resources :friendships - but this will be like a macro on creating standard action. And standard means in this case that POST is mapped to create.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other post, this is probably caused due to the fact that the default scaffolding for rails configures POST requests to work as create. To fix this, you can try something like this, although I'm not sure it will work.

```
   match "/friendships" => "friendships#create", :via => [:get]
   get   "/friendships" => "friendships#create"
```

The downside is that a `GET` request to `/friendships` will not give you the `index` action, as is the default case.

Maybe you can fix this with something like this:

```
match "/all_friendships", :to => "friendships#index", :via => :get, :as => :friendships
```