# The action could not be found for a controller. But it's present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this `sessions_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :login_joomla_user_or_redirect

  def create
    session[:joomla_user_id] = params[:joomla_user_id]
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:joomla_user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

And a basic route

```
unless Rails.env.production?
   get "login_as/:joomla_user_id" => "sessions#create", :as => :login
   get "logout"                   => "sessions#destroy"
end
```

I cannot understand why when I try to login with the route the browser return to me:

```
The action 'create' could not be found for SessionsController
```

The action is there. Why?
I'm migrating this code from Rails 4.2 to Rails 6

Comment: This has got to be the most insecure login ever devised. I can think of tons of ways to hack this like enumeration or a man in the middle attack.

Comment: @max I added a line. I use it in development because I don't have the joomla session for auth. Don't worry

Comment: There is nothing in the code in the question that explains the error. Are you sure thats the code actually running?

Comment: Yes, If I change "SessionsController" with "SessionController" it return initialized constant

Comment: have you got another sessions controller by any chance?

Comment: No... i0m getting crazy on this

Comment: @max skip_before_filter instead of skip_before_action. skip_before_filter is deprecated :-/ now it works

Comment: @RobertoPezzali As you have found the fix to your problem, you should consider adding it as an accepted answer to your own question to help assist other users experiencing this same issue in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: replace max `skip_before_filter` that is deprecated with `skip_before_action`
I don't know why Rails doesn't give another error.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your `create` and `destroy` methods to a `post`and `delete`.

See [ruby on rails use "create" method in controller as GET not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432149/ruby-on-rails-use-create-method-in-controller-as-get-not-working) for a similar question.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for the official guide on routes.

Comment: That wouldn't alter the behavior if they're being used as simple links, though, which are `GET` requests, as shown in the routing.

Comment: This is generally considered a practice from a security perspective https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147188/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-get-method-as-login-username-password-for-administrato

Comment: *shrug* I'm not addressing that at all; what I'm saying is that (a) if there's a comment regarding not-directly-related stuff in should be a comment, not an answer, and (b) this wouldn't help resolve the specific issue since the routes are explicitly defined as GET routes, so the link to the SO question isn't relevant.